# MySQL add array of names from the related table in select

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have the following database structure:

**events**

```
id
name
description
```

**event_activities**

```
event_id
activity_id
```

**activities**

```
id
name
```

I want to add sphinx search for events, which should include all related activities:

```
SELECT name, description, 
[Some SQL Magic that builds an array or string of names] as activities 
from events
```

So, the activities variable could be an array ['name1', 'name2'] or a string 'name1 | name2 | name3' and in case if one of the activity names is entered, it could include all the events that contain this activity into the search result.

Could someone help me figure out the [Magic] part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about the [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
SELECT e.name, e.description, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) AS activities
FROM events AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN event_activities AS ea ON ea.event_id = e.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN activities AS a ON ea.activity_id = a.id
GROUP BY e.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables together and select from activities using `IN`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

```
SELECT events.name, events.description 
FROM activities, event_activities, events 
WHERE activities.id=event_activities.activity_id 
    AND events.id=event_activities.event_id 
    AND activities.name in ('NAME1', 'NAME2', 'NAME3')
GROUP BY events.id
```